# Window Resize event not triggering when snapping windows to the edge of the screen with the mouse

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, vba

*This question is in relation to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352670/vba-windowresize-event-not-triggering-with-windows-snap), but I felt the issue at heart is less about programming and more about the limitations of the program, which is why I'm asking on here.*

I'm hoping someone will be able to explain the discrepancies I'm seeing with Windows Snap while using the Window Resize Event as a trigger for some VBA code.

I have this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module. It adds 1 to the value of `A1` in the first worksheet every time the window is resized:

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
Dim n As Integer

n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value = n + 1

End Sub
```

The event **will** trigger when:

- The window is maximized or minimized
- The window is resized by dragging the edges inwards/outwards
- The window is snapped to a side by pressing Windows+Arrow on the keyboard
- The window(a) is snapped to a side as a result of snapping another window(b) to one side and then choosing the first window(a) from the Windows Snap Assist thumbnails

The event **will not** trigger when:

- The window is snapped to a side by dragging the window to the edge of the screen with the mouse
- The window is unsnapped from a side by dragging the window with the mouse

**What I've Tried**

I've checked the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-windowresize-event-excel) for more details on the limitations of the Windows Resize event. As you can see from that link, there is not enough information there to be of much use in this situation.

I've also checked through Stack Overflow and Super User and haven't found any other questions mentioning using Windows Snap as a trigger for a Macro, other than the one referred to at the start of my question.

---

**Edit:** I've also tried Application_WindowResize, which is giving the same result.

I used this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module to initialize Application Events:

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

And this code after closing and reopening the workbook to check the event trigger:

```
Private Sub App_WindowResize(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window)
Dim n As Integer

n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value = n + 1

End Sub
```

For clarification, this code is being run in a fresh workbook, the earlier code is not present in the VBE. I'm seeing the same result as above, the event triggers for everything except dragging and snapping to the edge of the screen with the mouse.

---

Can anyone tell me why the Windows Resize event doesn't trigger for the cases above?

Comment: I am testing this, and also noticed that when you snap to the top(which actually maximizes), it doesn't trigger. When you unsnap, it counts 1. But if you unsnap from the top and straight snap to the left or right, it counts 2.

Comment: Workbook_WindowResize started having problems since Excel started having one workbook per application. It never worked when the workbook was maximized/minimized, and now it is always so within the application window. You might try to use instead [Application.WindowResize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-windowresize-event-excel).

Comment: @harrymc I've tried `Application.WindowResize` as per your advice and it is giving the same result. I'll add the details to my question.

Answer (score 2):

The Resize event was since always flaky in Excel and it has not improved
in the latest versions. It never fully worked in some cases involving
maximized or minimized windows and apparently snapping uses a similar
mechanism.

Solving the problem requires therefore interfacing directly with the
Windows API and intercepting the Windows messages relating to resize.

**Method 1 : Creating a new message pump for the application**

You will find the entire VB code in the last entry by Jaafar Tribak of the post
[Detecting the resizing of Excel's application window](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/187462-detecting-resizing-excels-application-window.html).

In a nutshell, you need to declare the Windows API functions of
`FindWindow` and `SetWindowLong` and use them to find the application window,
named `XLMAIN`, and set your own message pump.
You then intercept the relevant Windows messages, process them,
and finally pass them on to Windows.
The entire code is too long to reproduce here, and adapting it to your need
will require some knowledge of VB and Windows API.

**Method 2 : Use C DLLs**

For 32-bit versions of Excel, you might use the C DLL
(Dynamic Load Library) `SubCls.dll` and code module `modSubCls.bas`
downloadable from [this site](http://www.thevbzone.com/d_DLL.htm).

The description of how to use them can be found in the post
[Detect a window's re-size event](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/2008-02/msg03061.html).

I conclude by noting that I don't know of any easy solution to this problem.
I fear that you will need to do some heavy programming to work around these
shortcomings of Excel.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best I can get at the moment, I'll award the bounty but leave the question unanswered because I still don't know why the event doesn't trigger. (Other than it's probably a bug)